# Book suggestion for probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I need a good rigorous book to learn probability theory. So far, I've been suggested

- > Gnedenko’s  *Theory of Probability*;
- > Shiyayev’s *Probability*;
- > Feller’s *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*.

. Which one would you reccomend the most and why? Are there other books worth mentioning?

Comment: I really like Probability & Measure Theory by Ash and Doléans-Dade.

Comment: If you're a beginner, Probability Essentials by Jacod & Protter is really easy to read with short chapters and good exercises.

Comment: @OBDA I prefer something more advanced

Comment: Borovkov, Billingsley and Loève's books are all classics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an introductory course, you can look into **"Probability and Statistics in Engineering"**, by Hines, Montgomery, Goldman and Borror. It covers basic probability axioms, discrete and continuous distributions, before introducing statistics and data description techniques.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the topics you want to do also, but I found Applied Stochastic Processes by Lefebvre pretty decent for some probability theory topics.